# Migrate existing MVC4 app to Azure - 404 not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I have an existing MVC4 app that I'm trying to port to Azure for experimental purposes. I right clicked the app project and selected Add Azure Project or whatever. I then configured the Azure project settings as necessary and published to Azure.

After doing so, I can access static content just fine at the deployment url, but none of my controllers are responding - I just get a 404 not found error from IIS. What do I need to do to ensure that Azure starts up the ASP.NET bits so my app works correctly?

Comment: I think I need a bit more information to help you on this. When you set up the Azure project settings you added a web role, and set that web role to the MVC4 project correct?

Comment: Yes, the role was added to the Azure project and points to the correct MVC4 project.

Comment: Hmmm only 2 more things pop into my head now. Do you have a WebRole.cs file in your MVC4 project now? If so Maybe try creating a new project and make it a cloud project with MVC4. Then copy over yoru existing MVC4 project into the new cloud project.

Comment: I actually did create a new empty project and copied over the WebRole.cs (changed teh namespace too) just in case that was the problem, but it doesn't appear to have solved anything.

Comment: Ok, I am not to sure then. When I took an existing MVC3 project and did the Add Azure project. I got the Azure cloud project added to my solution, set up the web role to link to my existing MVC project and a WebRole.cs file was created in my existing project also. I would think about contacting Azure customer support http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/contact/ I have had good service from them

Comment: I just checked Elmah on the site and that loads fine, so ASP.NET is working, it just seems like the routing isn't...

Comment: Yeah now it sounds like a routing issue. But like I said above, if you are still having trouble contact Azure support and they can help you with the deployment of your project http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/contact/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving the issue by changing the os family from 1 (Windows 2K8 SP2) to 2 (Windows 2008 R2). I'd love to see some documentation on why this fixes the issue, but for now at least it's a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I tried to host my existing MVC application from my local computer to Azure. Please make sure of the following

1. Allow to run managed modules in the web.config like below
2. Remove the extensionless handler configuration like commented below

> ```
> *<system.webServer><modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />       
> <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
> </system.webServer>*
> ```